# “Move focus to the menu bar” shortcut does not work in Visual Studio Code in Big Sur?

Tags: macos, keyboard, visual-studio-code

I have customised the "Move focus focus to the menu bar" in Big Sur:

[image]

This combination does work in Google Chrome and Excel.

But hitting that key combination does nothing inside *Visual Studio Code* .  Is there any way to get this functionality?  I am using the latest version of vscode as of June 2021: 1.56.2

Note: this feature does work in *Catalina* (installed on my other laptop).

Comment: Were you able to try the suggestions I commented on your original SO post?

Comment: @JBallin  If I remember correctly your posts were about  verifying the _vscode_ shortcuts (as opposed to macOS shortcuts).  I actually had already *shared* the shortcuts on Vscode between the two macbook pros. One has the issue described and the other does not  - as noted in the question itself.   I have never used the specific combination of "Control;" for any shortcut in VsCode - or any other application since it is one I do use for the macOS for about 8 years. So we have one mac (catalina) that works normally and this new one (Big Sur) that does not.